sshd ignores Macs settings in sshd_config
I have tried deactivating weak MACs in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, this is the file:
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes

PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

DenyUsers www-data
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password

However even after rebooting, logging in with other MACs still works and "sshd -T | grep mac" still shows all MACs instead of just the ones I specified.
sshd clearly loads the file since it does not start when there is a syntax error in it so why does it ignore the MACs part?
